# Pages with tweet-sized ideas: use title tags or div/span/li for list items?

Tags: seo

We are working on a website (`https://mindool.com/p/583727136028889088/should-vaccines-be-required-for-children`) that does not display information in a conventional way in form of text paragraphs but in terms of ideas: one idea at a time of tweet size (lists of tweets).

We want to do SEO and are unsure how we should structure our HTML so that the search engine bots understand what we do. Our problem is, that we have no body text and only titles (H1/H2) on a page (we show the list items as H2).

We wonder if we should use div/span instead. Any suggestions are of course also welcome. We already use schema.org semantic annotations.

Here is a simplified version of a page:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>

<h1>Should vaccines be required for children?</h1>

<div>
Pros:
<h2>Vaccines have saved millions of lives since 1789.</h2>
<h2>Vaccines save more children from death or illness than it causes.</h2>
<h2>The side effects of vaccines are far less dangerous that the illness that children are exposed to when not vaccinated.</h2>
</div>

<div>
Cons:
<h2>Vaccines can cause serious and in some cases fatal side effects.</h2>
<h2>Parents should be free to decide what their kids should receive.</h2>
<h2>It is not up to the government to impose on parents what to do.</h2>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Please do not use 'external' short URLS, full URLS or internal short URLS only. This is because such URLS are out of your control and can be monetized.

Comment: Can you expand on *Currently, we show the list items as H2. This means we have only title text (H1/H2) and no body text.* so that it becomes clearer? For example, does *no body text* mean that there are no paragraph tags and only header tags? I am not sure what specifically you mean. A code sample could be helpful if this if possible. Otherwise, a better understanding would help me, at least, and likely others understand this portion of your question. Thanks!!

Comment: I added a simplified example. The idea to use H2 was to give the short-texts more importance, with the downside of having no body text at all.